# I want to draw all previous Days high and lows till beginning of stock

Tags: pine-script, stock, trading, metatrader4

I want to draw all high and lows of all days upto starting of stockk. I tried in how we write in python...
But it's not working. Help me how to draw all those lines dynamically without writing manually

````
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
y = 0
for i = 0 to 10
       y := y + 1
    hh := floor(security(tickerid, "D", high[y]))+0
    ll := ceil(security(tickerid, "D", low[y]))+0
    plot(hh, style=plot.style_line, title="Resistance Line", color=color.blue, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
    plot(ll, style=plot.style_line, title="Resistance Line", color=color.blue, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)```

I want horizontal lines without ending right side
````

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in indicator for this called Donchian Channels. I'm giving you my custom version that allows you to set the period (number of bars) for Highs and Lows separately.

```
//@version=4
study(title = "Donchian Channels", shorttitle = "DC", overlay = true)

Ulen = input(90, title = "Upper Channel", type = input.integer, minval = 3)
Llen = input(7, title = "Lower Channel", type = input.integer, minval = 3)

upper = highest(high, Ulen)
lower = lowest(low, Llen)
median = avg(upper, lower)

plot(upper, title = "Upper Channel", color = color.new(#4caf50, 0), linewidth = 2)
plot(lower, title = "Lower Channel", color = color.new(#f44336, 0), linewidth = 2)
plot(median, title = "Median", color = color.new(#ff9800, 0), linewidth = 2)
```

Comment: I want horizontal lines without ending

Comment: So you want to mark the all time high and all time low with horizontal lines?

Comment: So Donchian Channels works well for that. Just go on a daily chart and set it to a number of bars between 20 and 30. Or if you want to use a smaller timeframe increase the number of bars.